# How to convert array of 3 element arrays in to a hash where key is first 2 elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My problem is that I need to do efficient lookups of if a 2 element array and their corresponding value is nil. So if I have the following arrays:

```
arr1 = [
  [1, 2, 100],
  [3, 4, nil],
  [5, 6, 101]
]
```

I want something like

```
h = {
  [1, 2] => 100,
  [3, 4] => nil,
  [5, 6] => 101
}
```

So I can do something like:

```
error = []
arr2 = [
  [1,2],
  [3,4],
  [7,8]
]

arr2.each do |val|
  if h.include?(val)
    if h[val] == nil
      error << "Value is nil"
    else
      # Do something
    end
  else
    error << "Key doesn't exist"
  end
end
```

Comment: Please advise if the first 2 elements are guaranteed to be unique and if not how should we handle this e.g. `a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,7]]`

Comment: They are not guaranteed to be unique but we can overwrite or ignore duplicates. All we are about for the value is nil or not. So in that case `{[1,2] => 3, [4,5] => 6}` or `{[1,2] => 7, [4,5] => 6}` is fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that overwriting or ignoring duplicates is acceptable per your comment.

You can use `Enumerable#each_with_object` to iterate the `Array` and create a `Hash` like so

```
arr1 = [
  [1, 2, 100],
  [3, 4, nil],
  [5, 6, 101],
  [1, 2, nil],
]

arr1.each_with_object({}) do |(*first_two,last),obj| 
  obj[first_two] = last
end 
#=> {[1, 2]=>nil, [3, 4]=>nil, [5, 6]=>101}
```

You can ignore duplicates in a similar fashion

```
arr1.each_with_object({}) do |(*first_two,last),obj| 
  obj[first_two] = last unless obj.key?(first_two)
end 
#=> {[1, 2]=>100, [3, 4]=>nil, [5, 6]=>101}
```

Explanation:

- `each_with_object({})` will pass each element of of `arr1` to the block along with an object (a Hash in this case)
- `(*first_two,last),obj` - `*first_two` will collect everything up to `last` and `obj` is our Hash
- `obj[first_two] = last` simple Hash key assignment
- `each_with_object` returns the object (`obj` Hash in this case)

**Update** as recommended by @Stefan in ruby >= 2.7 you could also use

```
arr1.to_h {|*first_two,last| [first_two, last] }
```

This version will overwrite keys

Comment: In newer Ruby versions: `arr1.to_h { |*k, v| [k, v] }` (overwrites existing keys)

Comment: @Stefan I was completely unaware that `#to_h` now accepted a block. This is so much easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr1 = [
[1, 2, 100],
[3, 4, nil],
[5, 6, 101]
]

result = {}
arr1.each { |i| result[i.first(2)] = i.last }

=> {[1, 2]=>100, [3, 4]=>nil, [5, 6]=>101}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure every subarray during mapping and then convert result to hash with `Array#to_h` method

```
arr1 = [
  [1, 2, 100],
  [3, 4, nil],
  [5, 6, 101],
  [1, 2, nil],
]

arr1.map { |*first_two, last| [first_two, last] }.to_h
# => {[1, 2]=>nil, [3, 4]=>nil, [5, 6]=>101}
```

Duplicates will be overwritten

Answer (score -1):

In case if you need for two last values as key:

```
arr.map { |b| { b.shift => b }.invert }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).